Polars - Filter DataFrame using another DataFrame's row's
I have two Dataframes - graph and search with the same schema
Schema for graph:

SCHEMA = {
    START_RANGE: pl.Int64,
    END_RANGE: pl.Int64,
}

Schema for search:

SCHEMA = {
    START: pl.Int64,
    END: pl.Int64,
}

I want to search the graph dataframe.
For every row in search dataframe, I want to find all the rows in the graph dataframe where the START_RANGE and END_RANGE values are strictly within the range of the search dataframe.
How to achieve this using polars only?
Example -
graph = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "START_RANGE": [1, 10, 20, 30],
        "END_RANGE": [5, 15, 25, 35],
    },
)

search = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "START": [2, 11, 7],
        "END": [5, 14, 12], 
    },
)

# Expected output

[2,5] is in range [1,5]      ->    Where 2>=1   and 5<=5
[11,14] is in range [10,15]  ->    Where 11>=10 and 14<=15
[7,12] is not in any range 

output = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "START_RANGE": [1, 10],
        "END_RANGE": [5, 15],
    },
)


Can we assume that the ranges in graph are non-overlapping?

@Hericks - my bad for clarity, there can be overlapping ranges within the graph DF.

No, worries. Also, can you clarify, what you mean by "[6,9] in range [10,15]"?

@Hericks - Realised the expected output was incorrect - have fixed it. Also added an explainer.
Basically I want to search for all the rows in graph where the search START >= START_RANGE and search END <= END_RANGE for every row in search.

For future reference: Here is a link to the GitHub issue tracking the feature request of non-equi joins in polars .

Polars doesn't have full range joins but it does have join_asof which you can combine with a filter to get better performance than a full cross join filter. It's a left join so it'll have a return for every row in the left df.
It would look like
(
    search
    .sort('START')
    .join_asof(
        graph.sort('START_RANGE'), 
        right_on='START_RANGE', left_on='START'
        )
    .filter(pl.col('END')<=pl.col('END_RANGE'))
    .select('START_RANGE','END_RANGE')
)
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────┬───────────┐
│ START_RANGE ┆ END_RANGE │
│ ---         ┆ ---       │
│ i64         ┆ i64       │
╞═════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1           ┆ 5         │
│ 10          ┆ 15        │
└─────────────┴───────────┘

The join_asof ensures that START>=START_RANGE and then the post filter ensures that END<=END_RANGE
You can also approach it from the opposite angle like
(
    
    graph.sort('START_RANGE')
    .join_asof(
        search.sort('START'), 
       left_on ='START_RANGE', right_on='START',
       strategy='forward'
        )
    .filter(pl.col('START')>=pl.col('START_RANGE'))
    .select('START_RANGE','END_RANGE')
)

Depending on your data, one of those will be better than the other. For instance if you have
search = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "START": [2, 3, 11, 7],
        "END": [5, 4, 14, 12], 
    },
)

then the second approach returns the same thing as the original search but the first approach will return an extra row of (1, 5) because of the (3,4) row.

As the others have answered, inequality joins are not yet fully supported by Polars. If you have duckdb installed, you can leverage its support for this type of join and transition back to your Polars DataFrame quite readyily:
import polars as pl
import duckdb

graph = pl.DataFrame({
    "START_RANGE": [1, 10, 20, 30],
    "END_RANGE": [5, 15, 25, 35],
})

search = pl.DataFrame({
    "START": [2, 11, 7],
    "END": [5, 14, 12],
})

result = duckdb.sql('''
    select * from
    graph g, search s
    where (
      g.START_RANGE <= s.START
      and s.END <= g.END_RANGE
    );
''').pl()

print(result)
# shape: (2, 4)
# ┌─────────────┬───────────┬───────┬─────┐
# │ START_RANGE ┆ END_RANGE ┆ START ┆ END │
# │ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
# │ i64         ┆ i64       ┆ i64   ┆ i64 │
# ╞═════════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═════╡
# │ 1           ┆ 5         ┆ 2     ┆ 5   │
# │ 10          ┆ 15        ┆ 11    ┆ 14  │
# └─────────────┴───────────┴───────┴─────┘


join_where() was added in version 1.7.0, so it's possible to do non-equality joins now:
(
    graph.join_where(
        search,
        pl.col.START_RANGE <= pl.col.START,
        pl.col.END_RANGE >= pl.col.END
    ).drop('START', 'END')
)

┌─────────────┬───────────┐
│ START_RANGE ┆ END_RANGE │
│ ---         ┆ ---       │
│ i64         ┆ i64       │
╞═════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1           ┆ 5         │
│ 10          ┆ 15        │
└─────────────┴───────────┘


You could perform a cross-join then filter rows for which START_RANGE and END_RANGE is_between START/END. Optionally drop the intermediate columns and potential duplicates with unique if several ranges can be matched:
out = (graph.join(search, how='cross')
       .filter(pl.col('START').is_between(pl.col('START_RANGE'), pl.col('END_RANGE'))
              &pl.col('END').is_between(pl.col('START_RANGE'), pl.col('END_RANGE'))
              )
       .drop(['START', 'END'])
       .unique()
      )

If you are sure that START ≥ END, you could simplify to:
out = (graph.join(search, how='cross')
       .filter(pl.col('START').ge(pl.col('START_RANGE'))
              &pl.col('END').le(pl.col('END_RANGE'))
              )
       .drop(['START', 'END'])
       .unique()
      )

Output:
┌─────────────┬───────────┐
│ START_RANGE ┆ END_RANGE │
│ ---         ┆ ---       │
│ i64         ┆ i64       │
╞═════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 10          ┆ 15        │
│ 1           ┆ 5         │
└─────────────┴───────────┘


Hi @mozway - I had made an error in presenting the expected output. I have fixed the same, can you have a look once? Apologies!

@AshmeetLamba I see, then you can swap the names and use & in place of |
